# Using an MSBuild AfterBuild event to rename and copy a file?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I  have set up a AfterBuild target to copy Nuget packed file to our internal Nuget library whenever there is a Release build. That works perfectly.

What I would like to do is rename the Nuget package by adding -beta after the version number in the name when I build a debug version. How do I rename a file dynamically in MSBuild?

My current target script:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" >
<ItemGroup>
  <BetaNugetFile Include="$(OutputPath)$(TargetName).*.nupkg" />
  <NewNugetFile Include="$(OutputPath)$(TargetName).*.nupkg" />
</ItemGroup>
<Copy SourceFiles="@(NewNugetFile)" DestinationFolder="\\Server1\private\ITDev\Apps\NugetPackages" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'"/>
<Copy SourceFiles="@(BetaNugetFile)" DestinationFolder="\\Server1\private\ITDev\Apps\NugetPackages\beta" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'"/>
  </Target>
```

This script pushes the package to a beta directory but I want to rename and have it in the main library not in a subfolder.

Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. You can mark it as answer, which can be beneficial to other community members. It can be easier for them to search the solution.

Comment: Will as soon as SO's own answer timeout expires. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key was to use DestinationFiles instead of DestinationFolder

```
<Copy SourceFiles="@(BetaNugetFile)" DestinationFiles="\\Server1\private\ITDev\Apps\NugetPackages\%(Filename)-beta%(Extension)" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'"/>
```